# Rails Capistrano deploy fails with new gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rubygems, capistrano

First off let me say this is the first time I've deployed out a rails application so I'm pretty new to this. I have my production environment running successfully now and deployed it using Capistrano, but the deploy failed the first time due to missing gems. To get around it I basically cloned my repo on the server, ran

```
bundle install
```

This successfully installed the gems and Capistrano deployed successfully the next time around.

So with that in mind, is there a correct way to get new gems to install on each deploy?

My environment is Ubuntu Server, Apache2, Passenger, Rails.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the following in our deploy.rb

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
load 'deploy/assets'
before 'deploy', 'rvm:install_rvm'

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :rvm_ruby_string, ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"") # Read from local system
require 'rvm/capistrano'
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.3-p194'

...
```

Works like a treat for us although usually on a new build we'll have to install a few gems on the server directly.

Comment: Yep, the require at the top tells capistrano to execute the bundle install. Found that out just a few minutes ago after some intense googling. :D

Comment: Yeah, saw you'd answered your own one just after I hit Save :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the top of your config/deploy.rb file will make Capistrano execute bundle install.

require "bundler/capistrano"